# How to validate non required filed in Yup

Tags: regex, reactjs, formik, yup

How to validate a non required filed that should not contain the following special characters  `` #<`> `` and a white space before dot(.) I have Regex `` \`|\#|\&|\<|\ \.|\> `` to validate above condition but don't have any idea how to this regex with the yup.matches(). Thanks in advance

```
Regex: \`|\#|\&|\<|\ \.|\>
```

my validation schema is:

```
const validationSchema = function (values) {
  var regx = new RegExp(/\`|\#|\&|\<|\ \.|\>/gms);
    return Yup.object().shape({
      about: Yup.string()
      .matches(expression, 'about should not contain ` # < > \n')

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regular expression works you could use the [string.matches](https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-message-string--function-schema) function. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
var v = string().matches(/(hi|bye)/);
v.isValid('hi')
  .should.eventually()
  .equal(true);
v.isValid('nope')
  .should.eventually()
  .equal(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this today trying to solve same problem. I know i am late !

```
 return yup.object().shape(
    {
        about: yup
            .string()
            .nullable()
            .notRequired()
            .when("about", {
                // WARNING required itself => add cyclic dep at the end of the yup shape
                is: (value: string) => value?.length,
                then: (rule) => rule.matches(regx, "about should not contain ` # < > \n"),
            }),
    },
    // Add Cyclic deps here because when require itself
    [["about", "about"]]
);
```

Credit to this post : [Yup validation for a non-required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795388/yup-validation-for-a-non-required-field)

Please take a great care to the second parameter of the shape function. it will prevent cyclic check of the about on itself. (try it without, to see difference).